# FM Recording on Windows Mobile (Not Windows Phone)

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, audio-recording

I have a windows mobile 6.5 with FM facility. I am looking to develop an application for recording FM audio. I know that u can use phone camera to take pictures for your applications but not for audio. Where should i start from? Any Tutorial will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, unfortunately, no generic way to do it for two reasons:

1. The FM radio and its API is manufacturer specific.
2. The only Microsoft supported method of recording audio is from the microphone.

You will have to investigate the APIs provided by your OEM to see if they provide any mechanism for recording.